# How To Import History From Internet Explorer 7 To Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, history

I want to move/import history from Internet Explorer 7 in Windows XP to Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can export history from IE7, but I can find no way to import history into IE8 so far. [Use this software](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iehv.html) to export XP history to a chosen format

Comment: What will i do with exported file? If i could import it into Firefox or Chrome or Opera...